# Playwright - Locator for routerlink

Tags: playwright, playwright-dotnet

there is a button in the page with the sintax below

```
<div _ngcontent-cnw-c181="" class="col text-center ng-star-inserted">
<p _ngcontent-cnw-c181="" class="text-primary font-weight-bold">
Click the button below 
</p>
<button _ngcontent-cnw-c181="" type="button" routerlink="/web/click" class="btn btn-primary" tabindex="0" ng-reflect-router-link="/web/click">
<i _ngcontent-cnw-c181="" aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-check-circle"></i>
Click Here
</button>
</div>
```

but when I try to localize it using Locator, it returns the error: `Microsoft.Playwright.PlaywrightException: 'Unknown engine "routerlink" while parsing selector routerlink=/web/click'`

```
Page.Locator("routerlink=/web/click").ClickAsync();
```

The only solution I found is by searching for `"text=Click here"` but I would like to use the `"routerlink"` keyword instead because the text might change more often in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work: `Page.Locator("//button[@routerlink='/web/click']").ClickAsync();`

Comment: Sadly not. The sintax is of course right but it went to timeout. I added some code in the description, it might help

Comment: What's the exact error message?

Comment: Message:
    System.TimeoutException : Timeout 30000ms exceeded.
    =========================== logs ===========================
    waiting for selector "//child[@routerlink='/web/click']"
    ============================================================

  Stack Trace:
    Connection.InnerSendMessageToServerAsync[T](String guid, String method, Object args) line 161

Comment: Ouch, the locator should be `//button[@routerlink='/web/click']`, I've updated the answer. Please try again.

Comment: Now it's working, thank you very much. By the chance do you have any doc reference about this sintax? I've never seen before. I'm refering to the "//" and "[@rounterlink"

Comment: There's tons of. It's an `xpath` and it gets the element by the `attribute value`. Those to terms bring up plenty results in Google.